Technique / Algorithm of Decimate Modifier in Blender
I am currently working on a project to generate Levels of Detail (LODs) using the Decimate Modifier in Blender. As part of the theoretical component, I need to explain the algorithm or technique employed by the Decimate Modifier for mesh simplification. Specifically, I would like to know which algorithm the Decimate Modifier uses for mesh simplification. Is it the Quadric Error Metrics (QEM) algorithm or the Progressive Mesh Simplification algorithm?

Blender is open source, you can look through the code and find out all about it first hand

Looks like according to this line in the Blender source code it's using the Quadric algorithm.

Thanks a lot. yes I hav checked the source code and I think it is QEM algorithm
